# Apple sign in with Keycloak open id connect

Tags: keycloak, openid-connect, apple-sign-in

I am using keycloak for user authentication and have integrated google and facebook sign in with keycloak. I am trying to implement apple sign in with open id connect but getting unexpected error " internal server error" on redirect from apple sign in page.
Here is my idp configuration for apple on keycloak:

1- authorization url: https://appleid.apple.com/auth/authorize?response_mode=form_post

2- token url:https://appleid.apple.com/auth/token

3- disable user info: ON

4- Client Authentication: Client secret sent as post

5- default scopes: openid email

It took me more than a week and still could not resolve this problem